# How to get Drive Letter and Name (volume label)

Tags: c#, drive, driveinfo

I have a program that tells me all the hard disks/ usb's, but it only tells me the drive letter not the name.  Here is what I have:

```
DriveInfo[] drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
Console.WriteLine("Detected Drives: ");
for(int i = 0; i < drives.Count(); i++)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Drive " + i + ": " + drives[i].Name);
}

return drives;
```

and this prints:

```
Drive 0: C:\
Drive 1: E:\
```

but I want the name such as

```
Drive 0: C:\ Local disk
Drive 1: E:\ Kingston USB
```

how do I get this?

Comment: @Saravana, the linked question doesn't have an accepted answer, also the highest voted one might not be a good suit for OP

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are looking for the `VolumeLabel` property:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.volumelabel.aspx

Example:

```
Console.WriteLine(drives[i].VolumeLabel);
```

Comment: +1. As it answers the question as asked, also most likely it is not what OP is looking for (expected output seem to be looking for physical drive information, partially covered by [DriveInfo.DriveType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.drivetype.aspx) )

Comment: you can use `GetVolumeInformationA()` to obtain drive names from drive letters. For examples you can look at this https://codetwee.blogspot.com/2020/05/finding-volume-name-or-label-using.html

Answer (score 9):

Try this

```
 try
        {
            DriveInfo[] myDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

            foreach (DriveInfo drive in myDrives)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Drive:" + drive.Name);
                Console.WriteLine("Drive Type:" + drive.DriveType);

                if (drive.IsReady == true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Vol Label:" + drive.VolumeLabel);
                    Console.WriteLine("File System: " + drive.DriveFormat);

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
```